# Open a bootstrap modal with a link in d3 svg

Tags: d3.js, bootstrap-modal

I have created a d3.js tree and an interface based on bootstrap. Now I want to show more information to the user when clicking on any link within the tree. The information should be showed in an already existing bootstrap modal. How the information is loaded doesn't matter so far (I think I can do it with ajax). 
But I already fail at calling the modal to show up with a click on the link.

Here's the code from my tree.js where the link is created:

```
   nodeEnter.append("svg:a")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
        })      
        .attr("xlink:href", name) //this and the next line is just to give information for later ajax call
        .attr("type", type)
        .attr('data-toggle', 'modal') //this and the next line is for bs
        .attr('data-target', 'detail-modal')
    .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr('class', 'nodeText')
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);
```

This code results the following layout of each node (with the text as link):

```
 <g class="node" transform="translate(660,62.5)">
    <circle class="nodeCircle" r="4.5" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);</circle>

    <a x="-10" xlink:href="Malvaceae" type="plants_family" data-toggle="modal" data-target="detail-modal">
    <text dy=".35em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="end" style="fill-opacity: 1;" x="-10">Malvaceae</text></a>

    <circle class="ghostCircle" r="30" opacity="0.2" style="fill: red;" pointer-events="mouseover"></circle>
 </g>
```

Articles here and elsewhere seem not to deal with this problem, so I suspect that I missed something to make the d3.js knowing the bootstrap commands. But I cannot find out what or how to do this.

I would appreciate your help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample of an anchor tag within a SVG which on click opens up a modal. You've to add a basic shape (I used a `rect`) within the `anchor` tag.

**References:**

[Anchor tag in a SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a)

[Sample Bootstrap modal code](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

**Relevant code:**

```
anchor.append('rect')
.attr('width', 120)
.attr('height', 30)
.attr('x', 40).attr('y', 20)
.style('fill', '#ccc');
```

Here's a code snippet:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

var g = svg.append('g');

var anchor = g.append('a')
 .attr('href', '#')
  .attr('type', 'plants-family')
  .attr('data-toggle', 'modal')
  .attr('data-target', '#myModal').style('cursor', 'pointer');

anchor.append('rect').attr('width', 120).attr('height', 30).attr('x', 40).attr('y', 20).style('fill', '#ccc');

anchor.append('text').text('Sample modal!').attr('x', 50).attr('y', 40);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sample text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, after a while trying around I got it. But what is the thing behind the anchor? I didn't understand that really.